# Error- Invalid column name on using Update- database -Force in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-hosting

I am new to programming so please bear me for asking a nob question

I have created a C# project in Visual Studio 2013, and it is working fine on localhost, I have used code first approach to create my database and used `update-database` in package manager console (and it was done successfully), tables are created on local server and there was no error on inserting values, but problem started to come when I tried to duplicate that database to my web server (I am using window hosting provided by [bigrock][1], I am mentioning the steps used by me to duplicate my local server database to my hosting server.

1. created SQL Server database on hosting panel(plesk panel).
2. copied connection string and added to `web.config` in Visual Studio, after save rebuilt the project.
3. Now downloaded the SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, and filled details about my server database in "Connect Object Explorer" section, tested connection and its showing me all the databases hosted at that server with my database.
4. opened package manager console in Visual Studio (on my local server) and  used `enable-migrations` followed by `update-migrations`. And that is where I got the error Invalid column name 'xyz'.
5. next I checked my database in Management Studio, and there I can see all the tables created successfully with no column missing.

I ignored those errors at that time but when I tried to run my website and tried to register 1st user I got same errors with no idea where these are coming from

This is what I am getting on server (with whole stack trace):

> Invalid column name 'RegisteredDate'.
>   Invalid column name 'Name'.
>   Invalid column name 'Mobile'.
>   Invalid column name 'Email'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'RegisteredDate'.
>   Invalid column name 'Name'.
>   Invalid column name 'Mobile'.
>   Invalid column name 'Email'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'RegisteredDate'.
>       Invalid column name 'Name'.
>       Invalid column name 'Mobile'.
>       Invalid column name 'Email'.]
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789270
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340622
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +275
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +208
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
>          WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args) +111
>          WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.Execute(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +14
>          WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserRow(IDatabase db, String userName, IDictionary`2 values) +671
>          WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmation, IDictionary`2 values) +65
>          WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Object propertyValues, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +134
>          Riduk.Areas.Mobile.Controllers.AppStartController.Register(UserProfile model, String Password) +191
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690164
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

This is what I am getting on using `update-database` in package-manager console

> No pending explicit migrations.
>   Running Seed method.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'RegisteredDate'.
>   Invalid column name 'DOB'.
>   Invalid column name 'Email'.
>   Invalid column name 'Name'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.Execute(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserRow(IDatabase db, String userName, IDictionary`2 values)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmation, IDictionary`2 values)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Object propertyValues, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
>          at MyProject.Migrations.Configuration.SeedMembership() in c:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\MyProject\MyProject\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 62
>          at MyProject.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(UsersContext context) in c:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\MyProject\MyProject\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 31
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>       ClientConnectionId:1f5ed896-956b-43dd-a08c-ff86b144021f
>       Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
>       Invalid column name 'RegisteredDate'.
>       Invalid column name 'DOB'.
>       Invalid column name 'Email'.
>       Invalid column name 'Name'.

Here is my connection string from `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=103.xx.xx.xx2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=MyDatabase;Password=MyPassWord;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I hope this may be the sufficient for you guys to help a nob,

***Edit - deleted my models and schema for privacy concern

Comment: Without seeing your Database Schema, Code, as well as your `UDATE` Statement.. basically what you posted is kind of useless to us.. also have you tested this out locally before publishing ? also check this out for how to configure [Connection Strings](http://connectionstrings.com)

Comment: oops actually I was thinking the same that I missed something important while asking this question

Comment: yeah it was working perfectly on localhost

Comment: the infamous `It works on my machine` totally understandable.. but you need either add some relevant logging / tracking of where the actual error(s) are coming from.. perhaps you have your update statement on the remote site pointing to the incorrect database.. please provide more relevant information.. there is noway that someone can tell you what's wrong just looking at a StackTrace without seeing actual code..also does the Database allow for `NamePipes`

Comment: Ok I will try to use Sql Profiler(mentioned in one of the questions on SO), and will check about NamePipes with my service provider, after that I will update the progress

Comment: down-voters atleast mentioned the reasons for your action, that may help me to consider those things in future :P

Comment: that exception is usually thrown when the requested column is not there, so most likely your db schema is not correct. However I would not see why this would affect your update-database. most likely the command is cancelled (maybe because of accessibility) and then EF tries to materialize values in the program workflow, which do not have the required columnNames.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro by db Schema do you mean connection string ?

Comment: no, your database seems to be accessible. I mean the actual database schema (tables, columns in particular)

Comment: [MethodMan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/955076/methodman), I confirmed from the hosting provider they doesn't provide NamePipes

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to solve my problem but I found a workaround while chatting with bigrock support person,I took following steps to resolve my problem :-

1. Connected SQL Management Server Studio with my local database.
2. followed steps given [here](http://ruchirac.blogspot.in/2009/11/how-to-get-database-backup-from-sql.html) i.e. right click on the desired database -> Click Tasks -> Click Back Up -> click ok and a ".bak" file will be created at location specified by you.(note- file name must be .bak otherwise it will give error)
3. open plesk panel -> click on Backup Manager -> Database backup Repository -> Add backup -> Upload .bak file that you have created in step 2 -> click ok (ignoring all warning)
4. done everything is working fine.

**Note- still looking for the cause of error in previous method